# instantiating a class from another class in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was looking at linked list program in Python
I did'nt quite understand it.

I would appreciate if you help me on it.

Im pasting a part of code here, to simplify and understand one functionality

```
class node:

    def __init__(self,data,nnext=None):
        self.data = data
        self.nnext = nnext

class linkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def insertion(self,data):
        myinsertobj = node(data)
```

Here 
1. We have created a class for a node.
2. We created another class with a single head node.
3. In second class we have written a method for inserting. In the insertion() method, we are creating an object to the first class.

Now what I dont understand is, 
how to create object for the second class i.e linkedList class and how to call the insertion() Method,considering the above code only.(I don't want to use helper method yet)

Please help me understand it, as Im new to Python and trying to learn it.
The complete code is @ ==> https://www.educative.io/edpresso/how-to-create-a-linked-list-in-python

Also, Please suggest me few references for data structures in simple way.

Comment: The link explains it with examples very well: `ll = LinkedList()` and `ll.insert(my_data)`.

Comment: The above code doesn't work...

Comment: Hi @bereal ...Thank you very much for the reply.... in your comment, what is "my_data" ...is it some data i have to pass ..like ll.insert(3)...??? can you please give the complete steps for instantiating

Comment: @Sana what do you not understand about instantiating? Please, be specific. Have you tried anything? How did it not work?

Comment: @Sana yes it can be any data that you want to add to the list. If you walk through the entire tutorial, you'll know exactly how linked lists work.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga.  sorry I couldnt explain clearly...I wanted to know how to print this ```obj1 = linkedList()
                       obj1.insertion(10)```.  I want to get the o/p as 10

Comment: @Sana your linked list hasn't implemented anything to retrieve values from it. You should finish working through that tutorial. Please don't use this as a tutorial service, take a look at the [help] and [ask]. Note, asking for offsite resources if off-topic. You shouldn't be asking questions to guide you through third-party tutorials. By all means, feel free to ask a question, but make sure to look up the topic first, especially if it fundamental aspects of the language.

Comment: For that sort of thing, consider https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/ or a stack overflow [chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thanks again for guiding me (I really needed it :) )....now that if we consider only the code I wrote above....can we not print the value of the method insertion() ?

Comment: @Sana that method returns `None`. You can `print(obj1.insertion(10)` and it will print `None`.  Note, again, *the insertion method you have here doesn't work*. But you seem to be asking how to get to the value you should have inserted. Well, you have to write code to traverse your linked list to retrieve the value. Again, **please finishe reading the tutorial... the whole point of it is to show you how to work with linked lists. This is not a tutorial service.**

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga sure...appreciate ur help..thanks....actually I couldnt understand it properly from the tutorial.....so thought of posting here...now i got it :)

Comment: @Sana please do not post new questions on the main Stack Overflow site like this. Again, I provided a couple alternatives that are more suited to those sorts of questions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214875/discussion-between-sana-and-juanpa-arrivillaga).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the code you posted, in order to create an object for the second class, you would call

```
obj1 = linkedList()
```

where obj1 is now and instance of the linked list class.

To insert a node into obj1 you call the insertion method like so

```
obj1.insertion(data)
```

where data can be anything you want to insert.

Comment: ..awesome thank you very much....
suppose i do this 
                       ```obj1 = linkedList()
                       obj1.insertion(10)```

Now, how do I print this ??,,,I want to display the result of 10..appreciate your help

Comment: Well, heres where the code you posted is insufficient. While we can call the 'insertion' method on the linked list object, with the code you posted, calling this method will not do really do anything, i.e. no data is attached to the linked list object. In order to actually incorporate the node you should attach the node to the head, the way it is described in the insert method here: https://www.educative.io/edpresso/how-to-create-a-linked-list-in-python

Comment: @ Daniel Chavel (sorry not able to tag ur name)..Thanks a lot for the help..now I understand it :)...im trying to understand the code from past two days ...still struggling on it...hopefully I get through it..